I need a query like this in graphql but I can't figure out how to do it
I am making a car rental application to improve myself. .../vehicles address lists vehicles, I have 5 select inputs on the left side bar. If a value is selected, I want it to have a filter, if it is not selected, I want it to have no filter. I could not structure how to send the query and data. Can you help me?
subscription Vehicles($daily_price: String) {
      vehicles(where: { _or: { daily_price: $daily_price, fuel: {}, gear: {}, model_id: {}, brand_id: {} } }) {
  id
  fuel
}

const { data, loading, error } = useSubscription(from && to ? VEHICLES_BY_DATE_RANGE : VEH_SUBS, {
      variables: {
         ...filters,
      },
   });


Hey! First, why a subscription instead of an ordinary query? Second, you might want to generate proper typed queries with graphql-codegen. Third, it's not really clear what your problem actually is. How to use useSubscription? Fourth, it's looks to me as if you want to filter by date, but your where filter doesn't cover that - just daily_price etc. Fifth, how does filters actually look like? Or does it depend on from && to as well? Sixth, how does the VEHICLES_BY_DATE_RANGE look like? - You only showed the other one.

Also not that you can pass skip: true as an option - so it might make sense to use to different hooks for each query and variables, but pass something like skip: from && to  resp. skip: !(from && to) to ensure only the right one gets invoked.

I’m sorry, subscription because Reservations can be made instantly and vehicle availability is subject to change.and VEHICLES_BY_DATE_RANGE is not important because i dont use now but i just forget it there. My problem is Making queries that can sometimes be empty and sometimes full, for example, someone may want to filter the price range of the vehicle but someone else may not, how should I manage this?

I'm still having a hard time understand what your problem is. If you want to filter for, say, the price, pass when: { daily_price: "50"} in the variables. If you don't want to filter, don't pass variables. So what's exactly the issue?

Now, to run a query, for example, I have to define a query like subscription Vehicle($daily_price:String){vehilces(where: _or:{daily_price:$daily_price})}{id} but when I send a query like const { data, loading, error } = useSubscription(VEH_SUBS, {
variables: {},
}); or if I send the daily_price as an empty object or an empty string like "" in the variables, it doesn't work.

What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? An error? Wrong results? Looking at your snippets, I don't even know whether where is a mandatory parameter, or if where._or is. According to your declaration, daily_price is optional (b/c it's String and not String!, but for everything else, I cannot tell. Mandatory objects must be passed, ofc., for example with variables: { where: { _or: {}}}, But really, it's just guesswork without the schema.

I don't know if labeling is possible, I wrote the way I solved it below.

Alright, here's a sketch on how to work with variables. The type declaration are just based on what I assume to be correct based on your code snippets, so you might have to adjust them.
// I'm skipping the definition of how the Where filters, so here's just the query:
const VEH_SUBS = gql`
  subscription getVehicles($where: Where!) {
    vehicles(where: $where) {
      model {
        name
      }
    }
  }`;

// I'm assuming the type of the filters based on your code snippets. They could be wrong (e.g. brand_id could be a number).
const createQuery = (filters: { brand_id?: string, fuel?: string, }) => {
  // I'm assuming the type of the filterConditions based on your code snippets. It's probably not complete. 
  const filterConditions: {
    where: { _or: { brand_id?: { _eq?: string }, fuel?: { _eq?: string } } }
  } = { where: { _or: {} } };

  // Setup filterConditions. Ofc, this could be done direclty in the line above, but I keep it separate so it might be easier to follow.
  if (filters?.brand_id) filterConditions.where._or.brand_id = { _eq: filters.brand_id };
  if (filters?.fuel) filterConditions.where._or.fuel = { _eq: filters.fuel };

  const { data: d, loading: l, error: e } = useSubscription(
    VEH_SUBS, // This should be a query which accepts where as argument!
    { variables: {where: filterConditions }}
  );
  ...
};

Again, I'ld recommend you to utilize graphql-codegen instead of explicit type assumption as I did, and also instead of any as you did.

I don't know exactly what codegen is but I will look into it. Thank you very much again for your interest.

@EnesSEVAL You're welcome!

I know I didn't explain my problem properly.
I solved it like this, maybe you can understand by looking at it:
const createQuery = (filters: any) => {
      const filterConditions = [];

      if (filters?.brand_id) filterConditions.push(`brand_id : {_eq: "${filters.brand_id}"}`);
      if (filters?.fuel) filterConditions.push(`fuel: {_eq: "${filters.fuel}"}`);
      let q;
      if (filterConditions.length > 0) {
         q = `
            {
               _or: {${filterConditions.join(", ")}}
            }
         `;
      } else q = "{}";

      return gql`
            subscription getVehicles {
               vehicles(where: ${q}) {
                  model {
                     name
                  }
               }
            }
         `;
   };

   const q = createQuery(filters);

   const { data: d, loading: l, error: e } = useSubscription(q);

I really thank you for your interest, but I would appreciate it if you could understand the problem and explain a different solution.
